# CI Session is not working

Tags: codeigniter, session

We are using CI (ver 2.2.1). We are creating a session, based on url and based on session value, we do some functionalists in Controller and send to view. When we hit the view, undefined error is coming at very first time. when i refresh the page, the view load properly.

We are creating the session in Modal file:

```
$this->session->set_userdata('url_data',$total_result);
```

$total_result has array value.

My Controller:

```
if(isset($plan_id) && $plan_id!=''){ .... } 
else { 
$sessData = $this->session->userdata('url_data'); 
$planid = $sessData['id'] ;
$plan_details = $this->mymodel->modelname("...where id = $sessData['id']")
}
```

Very first time, I had a Error like

```
Undefined index: id
```

Comment: $total_result = array( 'id' => 2, 'name' => 'somename',....)

Comment: Can you printout `$sessData`